# Ошибка при создании одного вида для регистрации и входа с помощью yii2-user

Tags: yii2

Добрый день, всем!Хочу сделать один вид для регистрации и входа.. Попыталась использовать для этого виджет входа.

Прописала в dectrium\views\security\login.php следующий код как в документации yii2-user и при открытии этой страницы вышла следующая ошибка:

```
PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: dektrium\user\models\LoginForm::email'

in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:147

Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(2081): yii\base\Component->__get('email')
#1 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(1264): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::getAttributeValue(Object(dektrium\user\models\LoginForm), 'email')
#2 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(1313): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeInput('text', Object(dektrium\user\models\LoginForm), 'email', Array)
#3 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(395): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeTextInput(Object(dektrium\user\models\LoginForm), 'email', Array)
#4 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(204): yii\widgets\ActiveField->textInput()
#5 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(176): yii\widgets\ActiveField->render()
#6 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\views\security\login.php(40): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString()
#7 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(328): require('C:\\Users\\acer\\O...')
#8 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\Users\\acer\\O...', Array)
#9 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(152): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\Users\\acer\\O...', Array, Object(dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController))
#10 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(381): yii\base\View->render('login', Array, Object(dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController))
#11 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\controllers\SecurityController.php(166): yii\base\Controller->render('login', Array)
#12 [internal function]: dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController->actionLogin()
#13 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#15 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#16 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('user/security/l...', Array)
#17 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#18 C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\web\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#19 {main}

1. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php at line 314
305306307308309310311312313314315316317318319320321322323

    /**
     * Converts an exception into a PHP error.
     *
     * This method can be used to convert exceptions inside of methods like `__toString()`
     * to PHP errors because exceptions cannot be thrown inside of them.
     * @param \Exception $exception the exception to convert to a PHP error.
     */
    public static function convertExceptionToError($exception)
    {
        trigger_error(static::convertExceptionToString($exception), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    /**
     * Converts an exception into a simple string.
     * @param \Exception $exception the exception being converted
     * @return string the string representation of the exception.
     */
    public static function convertExceptionToString($exception)
    {

2. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php at line 178 – yii\base\ErrorHandler::convertExceptionToError()
3. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\invest\vendor\dektrium\yii2-user\views\security\login.php at line 40 – yii\widgets\ActiveField::__toString()
34353637383940414243444546

                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id'                     => 'registration-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                    'enableClientValidation' => false,
                ]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

                <?php if ($module->enableGeneratingPassword == false): ?>
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
                <?php endif ?>
```

Вот файл login.php:

```
<?php

use dektrium\user\widgets\Login;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View              $this
 * @var dektrium\user\models\User $user
 * @var dektrium\user\Module      $module
 */

$this->title = Yii::t('user', 'Sign up');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title"><?= Yii::t('user', 'Sign in') ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?= Login::widget() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><?= Html::encode($this->title)     ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id'                     => 'registration-form',
                'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => false,
            ]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

            <?php if ($module->enableGeneratingPassword == false): ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('user', 'Sign up'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block']) ?>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center">
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('user', 'Already registered? Sign in!'), ['/user/security/login']) ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

А также файл web.php:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/views/user'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'Q3RvvGeA0IPRTfyXmNeXd46HHcT1raba',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'enableUnconfirmedLogin' => true,
            'enableFlashMessages' => true,
            'enableRegistration' => true,
            'enableGeneratingPassword' => true,
            'enablePasswordRecovery' => true,
            'confirmWithin' => 21600,
            'urlPrefix' => 'user',
            'cost' => 10,
            'admins' => ['admin']
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cудя по всему в файл `login.php` вы из контроллера передаёте `$model` - экземпляр класса `dektrium\user\models\LoginForm`. А внутри `LoginForm` нет поля `email`. Там есть только `login`, `password` и `rememberMe`. В контроллере на вьюху передайте экземпляр класса `dektrium\user\models\RegistrationForm` внутри переменной `$model`.

То есть в контроллере должна быть строка:

`$model = new RegistrationForm();`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, действительно всё так и было